# Unable to launch SAP session on locked screen

Tags: python-3.6, autoit, rpa, sap-gui

I need to open SAP and launch the required session. I am unable to get the selector details for session name with AutoIt Window Info tool so I :

- Press down arrow x number of times.
- Press enter.

```
autoit.run(CONFIG.get("SAP", "logon_path"))
process_id = os_utils.get_process_id(Cons.SAP_TASK_NAME)
print("Process pid:" + str(process_id))
autoit.win_wait_active("[TITLE:SAP Logon 720]")
autoit.win_activate("SAP Logon 720")
autoit.send("{PGUP}")
for i in range(1, int(channel)):
    autoit.send("{DOWN}")
autoit.send("{ENTER}")
autoit.win_wait_active("[CLASS:SAP_FRONTEND_SESSION]")
```

This works when logged in to the Windows VM. But as this is an RPA process I ensure a user session is created in the live environment:

```
%windir%\System32\tscon.exe 2 /dest:console
```

When I run my SAP login script after creating this session it launches the SAP environment selection window, but the keyboard events don't happen until I log in to the VM manually.

I tried to give the keyboard event directly to the window but that did not work. I decided to add a one time SAP login and let it lie connected which is not the best approach.

Comment: The problem with GUI automation is, that if there is no GUI, there can not be automation. *Maybe* `ControlSend` can help (it works for a minimized Window, but I never tried with a locked system (my guess would be it doesn't).

Comment: Tried with control send as well, where we give a window name. But it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid so. After all, locking the screen is supposed to prevent interaction with the system.